# javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, netbeans

Hi i am Creating my webservices and for data access i have used JPA(Hibernate), mysql and Glassfish server inside Netbeans IDE.

I am getting following exceptions while accessing:

```
**Client Side logs :**
----------------------

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name
javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for hrdb; 
in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,
 java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl,
 java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
 [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: hrdb not found]

**Server side logs**
--------------------

Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[com.mycompany.fkemployeeservices.ApplicationConfig]: Servlet.service() for servlet com.mycompany.fkemployeeservices.ApplicationConfig threw exception
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: hrdb not found
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:237)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:204)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:66)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:478)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:622)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:421)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:421)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:399)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:73)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at entitycontrollers.ControllerFactory.getController(ControllerFactory.java:30)
    at data.EmployeeDetailsOperations.<init>(EmployeeDetailsOperations.java:24)
    at com.mycompany.fkemployeeservices.FKServicesCentralResource.getEmployeeDetails(FKServicesCentralResource.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Controller factory

```
package entitycontrollers;

import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class ControllerFactory {

  public static EvaEmpDetailsJpaController getController() {
         return new EvaEmpDetailsJpaController(Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("com.mycompany_FKEmployeeServices_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU"));
    }
}
```

Entity Controllers
    package entitycontrollers;

```
import dbentity.EvaEmpDetails;
import ApplicationSpecificClasses.exceptions.NonexistentEntityException;
import ApplicationSpecificClasses.exceptions.PreexistingEntityException;
import ApplicationSpecificClasses.exceptions.RollbackFailureException;
//import dbentity.EvaEmpDetails;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;
import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;

/**
 *
 * @author mukul.kumar
 */
public class EvaEmpDetailsJpaController implements Serializable {

    public EvaEmpDetailsJpaController(UserTransaction utx, EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        this.utx = utx;
        this.emf = emf;
    }
    private UserTransaction utx = null;
    private EntityManagerFactory emf = null;

    public EvaEmpDetailsJpaController(EntityManagerFactory createEntityManagerFactory) {
       // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        this.emf = createEntityManagerFactory;
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void create(EvaEmpDetails evaEmpDetails) throws PreexistingEntityException, RollbackFailureException, Exception {
        EntityManager em = null;
        try {
            utx.begin();
            em = getEntityManager();
            em.persist(evaEmpDetails);
            utx.commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            try {
                utx.rollback();
            } catch (Exception re) {
                throw new RollbackFailureException("An error occurred attempting to roll back the transaction.", re);
            }
            if (findEvaEmpDetails(evaEmpDetails.getId()) != null) {
                throw new PreexistingEntityException("EvaEmpDetails " + evaEmpDetails + " already exists.", ex);
            }
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            if (em != null) {
                em.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public void edit(EvaEmpDetails evaEmpDetails) throws NonexistentEntityException, RollbackFailureException, Exception {
        EntityManager em = null;
        try {
            utx.begin();
            em = getEntityManager();
            evaEmpDetails = em.merge(evaEmpDetails);
            utx.commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            try {
                utx.rollback();
            } catch (Exception re) {
                throw new RollbackFailureException("An error occurred attempting to roll back the transaction.", re);
            }
            String msg = ex.getLocalizedMessage();
            if (msg == null || msg.length() == 0) {
                Long id = evaEmpDetails.getId();
                if (findEvaEmpDetails(id) == null) {
                    throw new NonexistentEntityException("The evaEmpDetails with id " + id + " no longer exists.");
                }
            }
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            if (em != null) {
                em.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public void destroy(Long id) throws NonexistentEntityException, RollbackFailureException, Exception {
        EntityManager em = null;
        try {
            utx.begin();
            em = getEntityManager();
            EvaEmpDetails evaEmpDetails;
            try {
                evaEmpDetails = em.getReference(EvaEmpDetails.class, id);
                evaEmpDetails.getId();
            } catch (EntityNotFoundException enfe) {
                throw new NonexistentEntityException("The evaEmpDetails with id " + id + " no longer exists.", enfe);
            }
            em.remove(evaEmpDetails);
            utx.commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            try {
                utx.rollback();
            } catch (Exception re) {
                throw new RollbackFailureException("An error occurred attempting to roll back the transaction.", re);
            }
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            if (em != null) {
                em.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public List<EvaEmpDetails> findEvaEmpDetailsEntities() {
        return findEvaEmpDetailsEntities(true, -1, -1);
    }

    public List<EvaEmpDetails> findEvaEmpDetailsEntities(int maxResults, int firstResult) {
        return findEvaEmpDetailsEntities(false, maxResults, firstResult);
    }

    private List<EvaEmpDetails> findEvaEmpDetailsEntities(boolean all, int maxResults, int firstResult) {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        try {
            CriteriaQuery cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
            cq.select(cq.from(EvaEmpDetails.class));
            Query q = em.createQuery(cq);
            if (!all) {
                q.setMaxResults(maxResults);
                q.setFirstResult(firstResult);
            }
            return q.getResultList();
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }

    public EvaEmpDetails findEvaEmpDetails(Long id) {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        try {
            return em.find(EvaEmpDetails.class, id);
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }

    public int getEvaEmpDetailsCount() {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        try {
            CriteriaQuery cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
            Root<EvaEmpDetails> rt = cq.from(EvaEmpDetails.class);
            cq.select(em.getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
            Query q = em.createQuery(cq);
            return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }
 }
```

> Please comment for any other required files i need to put here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the pom.xml file dependencies of unknown.binary were created.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen-4.3.1.Final</artifactId>
        <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin</artifactId>
        <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen-4.3.1.Final</artifactId>
        <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

On removing these dependencies **Unable to build entity manager factory** error is removed.